# docker-compose: command not found jenkins Pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

when i trying to start this code https://github.com/Sabrjkee/docker-qrcode-generator.git in blue ocean i recive this massege

```
> [ker-qrcode-generator_master-RJ4RZWEFLU27HJ7Q4MAGBQFTT7E6MLQM6BRPZAHRAEYIU27NR5VA]
> Running shell script
> 
> + docker-compose --version
> 
> /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ker-qrcode-generator_master-RJ4RZWEFLU27HJ7Q4MAGBQFTT7E6MLQM6BRPZAHRAEYIU27NR5VA@tmp/durable-4dbe9184/script.sh:
> line 2: docker-compose: command not found
> 
> script returned exit code 127
```

in console

```
$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.17.0, build ac53b73
$ docker --version
Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 3dfb8343b139d6342acfd9975d7f1068b5b1c3d3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like folder where `docker-compose` binary file is is not included into `PATH` in your Jenkins pipeline.

You can add it using `environment` section:

```
pipeline {

    environment {
        PATH = "$PATH:<folder_where_docker-compose_is>"
    }
}
```

For example, if `docker-compose` is located in:

```
$ which docker-compose
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

`Jenkinsfile` will be modified to:

```
pipeline {

    environment {
        PATH = "$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
    }
}
```